# table join with count() condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find all patrons that have at least 1 circulation record. Here's what I currently have, but it only finds one result. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM patrons 
    INNER JOIN circulations on circulations.patron_id = patrons.id 
HAVING COUNT(circulations.id) > 0
```

I didn't give the table structures since I figured it wasn't needed for the solution. If it is needed, let me know and I'll try to add it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM patrons 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM circulations 
              WHERE circulations.patron_id = patrons.id)
```

Comment: I like this because it doesn't group the patrons. Is there a way to find out how many circulation records there are for each patron in the same query?

Comment: Sure, but that's a different question, so ask another one; this was also a good question and has some good answers, so don't go changing it.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patrons 
    INNER JOIN circulations on circulations.patron_id = patrons.id 
GROUP BY patrons.id
```

Comment: This should do it, but *only* for MySQL.  Other databases *reaaaaaly* hate this construct.  For those, you would have to spell out every column of `patrons` in the group by, or else do a subquery on just `patrons.id` and join *that* to the `partrons` table in the outer query.  +1 anyway...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my sample:

Supposed PatronName is column on your patrons table.

```
SELECT PatronName,COUNT(circulations.id) as CountCirculation
FROM patrons 
    INNER JOIN circulations on circulations.patron_id = patrons.id 
group by PatronName
HAVING COUNT(circulations.id) > 0
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
select *
from patrons p
left join circulation c on c.patron_id = p.id
where not c.patron_id is null
```